# Install ElasticSearch on Gentoo

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, installation, gentoo

Trying install ElasticSearch on Gentoo, but there are a lot of errors happened. Is there any way to install ES not from source code for common linux distribution, but using some package manager like emerge or something similar. I'm not really familiar with Gentoo OS, so please help me with detail steps. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Elasticsearch running by following these steps:

```
# Install ES
emerge --ask --autounmask=y --autounmask-write app-misc/elasticsearch
etc-update
type: "-3" & hit ENTER
type: "y" & hit ENTER
emerge --ask app-misc/elasticsearch

# Install Java
emerge --autounmask=y --autounmask-write --ask --oneshot virtual/jdk
etc-update
type: "-3" & hit ENTER
type: "y" & hit ENTER
emerge --ask --oneshot virtual/jdk

# Create a symbolic link to java
mkdir -p /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin
ln -s /opt/icedtea-bin-3.16.0/bin/java /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java

# Start ES
systemctl start elasticsearch

# Make a request to ES
curl localhost:9200
```